# gmail not sending email anymore

Tags: c#, .net, email, gmail

I was using a gmail account to send email from an app, 
I have set "allow less secure app", and the list on "Recent Security Events" is empty.

Up until today it was working, but today it started saying:

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not
>   authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required

I can still send email using the gmail website and using thunderbird it still works, but not in the app,

if I change in my code the username and password to a different gmail account it works, but not with this particular one.

this is the code I use to send email:

```
var client = new SmtpClient
{
    Host = serverName,
    Port = 587, // TLS Port
    EnableSsl = true,
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, pass)
};

using (var message = new MailMessage(new MailAddress(userName), new MailAddress(to))
{
    Subject = subject,
    Body = body
})
{
    client.Send(message);
}
```

UPDATE:
all of a sudden it started to work (on my local, I have unite tests that send email), don't know why, I checked the deployed app it also started to send emails

UPDATE2:
seems to be a more global problem: https://productforums.google.com/forum/?nomobile=true&hl=en&utm_source=google-account&utm_medium=web#!topic/gmail/NETOwtLyWGI

Comment: are you receiving any security alerts in gmail inbox? did you enable 2fa by any chance?

Comment: No, I'm not receiving any alerts, and 2fa is  not enabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my searchings, I've found a few things to try:

1. Try changing password to more complex/secure password. On occasion it seems that Gmail starts to require more complex passwords without letting people know and/or throwing proper errors.
2. Remove "EnableSsl = true," line from code. (or set to false) ([Link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/aea21122-d5d5-4c7b-95d5-43aabb72b9dd/the-smtp-server-requires-a-secure-connection-or-the-client-was-not-authenticated-the-server?forum=exchange2010))
3. The fact that your code just stopped working randomly may suggest something along the lines of an expired certificate that is still being presented.

Question: When you say you are able to send email from that account via browser and via Thunderbird, are you sending those emails from the same machine as the C# application attempts to?

Comment: my password is quite long around 20 chars and has all the signs an upper lower number, I tried to run the application locally from the same machine as thunderbird and chrome+gmail site, same problem

Comment: if I set ``EnableSsl = false` I'm getting: "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS"

Comment: Try port 465 (SSL) instead of 587 (TLS)? Not a long term solution, but worth trying to troubleshoot.

Comment: actually all of a sudden it started to work (on my local) , don't know why, maybe it was a glitch in the gmail, or somebody from the gmail team saw this post, I checked the deployed app it also started to send emails

Comment: I'm betting its a cert in that case. I wish I had more expertise in this area, but I'm guessing that when sending via local machine, it used updated certs. I'm guessing if you log in to the server that your C# app is using, and send an email via browser, that it may indeed also start working after cert is updated. Again, wish I had more expertise in this area.

Comment: found this thread maybe this is the problem: https://productforums.google.com/forum/?nomobile=true&hl=en&utm_source=google-account&utm_medium=web#!topic/gmail/NETOwtLyWGI

Comment: Looks about right. Google SRE team to the rescue - Lets see if it starts working again soon. We might be in that .01 downtime of of 99.99% uptime.

Answer (score 0):

As of October 30, 2023, I have a working solution when "Add another email address" isn't accepting security credentials in gmail.

Technical Notes: I have Google Workplace, so my gmail is on that. I had less secure apps enabled but now I have 2FA turned on, which overrides that. Also, most of the solutions for configuring an app-specific passwords (including google's own documentation as of today and their support volunteers on their forums) cite outdated information - E.g indicating you can choose an app type (e.g. 'mail') which is no longer available. Account specifIt's under myaccount.google.com/security by clicking on 2-Step Verification and going to App Passwords. Google will probably move it/change it again tomorrow.

Solution:

1. Step 1 - get your app-specific password - doesn't matter what you call it - crucially: take out the spaces
2. Step 2 - "quarantine" your gmail account by clicking your avatar at the top and logging out of all accounts (if you're logged into any other google accounts) - make sure. THen log back into the one you're trying to add an email address to.
3. Step 3 - configure as normal: send-from email, alias = yes, TLS 587 smtp.gmail.com but use your current account gmail address and the modified app password above.
4. Step 4 - click the link in the confirmation email

Again, this works for me when all other solutions fail as of 10/30/23 but google will likely change something again tomorrow.

If anyone knows of an easy SMTP server I could spin up on my own cloudways account or digital ocean that will accept any email address on any domain I own and let me use the smtp server in gmail setup, please let me know. I'm tired of chasing this pony every time google changes protocols and the send-from addresses stop working :)